# NameError: name 'training' is not defined

Tags: python

while I stored the images in numpy array from the train_imgs, I got this error.

```
for batch in train_imgs:
  for img in batch[0]:
   img = np.reshape(img,(1,256,256,3))
   training = np.vstack((img, training))
```

Can someone tell me what am I missing, please?

Comment: I think what you want is to initialize training variable as an empty array with the proper shape. Because in the line `training = np.vstack((img, training))` Python interpreter is clueless what `training` variable is.

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet, you have `training = np.vstack((img, training))`.

The error seems to occur because of the `training` inside of `vstack` function. You try to replace `training` with `training` when `training` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference a variable that is still undefined.

```
training = np.vstack((img, training)) # training isnt defined yet
```

In the execution priority on this snippet, the last action to take place is the assignment, so when you try to reference `training` in:

```
np.vstack((img, training))
```

The compiler could not find any definition for `training` at that moment.

You should initialize the training variable first and later make use of it.